# Deleted files re-appear in AD structure, on logout profile-saving gives "permission denied"

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, roaming-profile

I have a user on Windows XP that has their profile stored on Server 2008.

The user complains about not being able to delete files in their documents directory because they re-appear. On logging out and shutting down, there's an error message about not being able to save the profile back to the server - permission denied.

Checking the error log in the user's machine also gives me error 1525.

What should I do to repair the user's profile? There haven't been any changes in server configuration and no other users (XP and 7) experience the same issue.

Comment: rtfm much? this is trivial and has been answered a million times.

Comment: What is the solution then?